# vue3 + pinia: how to make reactive a value from the store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, reactive, pinia

I am using vue 3 with composition api and pinia

I have an auth store that is reading from the store a default email and a default password

```
import { useAuthStore } from "stores/auth";
const authStore = useAuthStore();

const email = authStore.loginUser;
const password = authStore.passwordUser;
```

Then I am using email and password as `v-model`.

The problem is that both are not reactive. If I change the value from the text input, the model is not updated

I ask kindly for *an explanation* of the problem and a solution.

Comment: It's unclear what behavior you expect. Do you want to change authStore via v-model?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```js
// ❌ loses reactivity
const email = authStore.loginUser
```

creates an `email` constant with the current value of `authStore.loginUser`, losing reactivity. To keep reactivity, you could use `computed`:

```
import { computed } from 'vue'

// ✅ keeps reactivity
const email = computed({
  get() { return authStore.loginUser },
  set(val) { authStore.loginUser = val }
})
// email is now a computed ref
```

...or you could use the provided [storeToRefs](https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/modules/pinia.html#storetorefs) wrapper, designed for extracting/deconstructing store reactive props while keeping their reactivity (basically to avoid the above boilerplate):

```
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
// ✅ keeps reactivity
const { 
  loginUser: email,
  passwordUser: password
} = storeToRefs(authStore)
// email & password are now refs
```

---

**Important**: you only want to deconstruct `state` and `getters` using `storeToRefs`. Actions should be used directly from the store object (`authStore` in your case) or deconstructed without the wrapper:

```js
const { actionOne, actionTwo } = authStore
```

This is specified in docs linked above:

> *... so methods and non reactive properties are completely ignored.*

---

In conclusion, you typically end up with two deconstructions from each store:

```js
import { useSomeStore } from '@/store'
// reactive:
const { s1, s2, g1, g2 } = storeToRefs(useSomeStore())
// non-reactive:
const { a1, a2 } = useSomeStore()
```

where `s1`, `s2` are `state` members, `g1`, `g2` are `getters` and `a1`, `a2` are `actions`.

Comment: IMO `storeToRefs` just replaces one boilerplate with another, worse kind. Now you have to do ritual storeToRefs for all your refs (which ARE refs inside store's definition), and you have to explicitly separate state from methods every time you use the stuff (more cognitive complexity in exchange for nothing).

I just don't get why pinia thinks it's a good idea to break defined refs with reactive object (which is bad with object destruction) and have more trouble instead of less.

Comment: Here's how I look at it: 1) `pinia` needs way less boilerplate than `vuex`. 2) a store's state is not exactly `ref`s, it's `reactive`. If you want the inner props of a `reactive` to remain reactive you either access them through the reactive container (in this case: `state.myProp`) or you have to convert them to refs, just like you do when you decompose a `reactive` for template `...toRefs(myContainer)`. Last, but not least, `pinia` was created because someone felt about `vuex` the way you feel about `pinia`. Maybe something even better will come out of your dissatisfaction with `pinia`.

Comment: Anything related to `vuex` is irrelevant as `pinia` positions itself not as "newer version of vuex", but "the store for vue" - so general "to go" state management for `vue`. And yes I understand how ref and reactive works thanks, it still doesn't explain `pinia`'s decisions on it's API.


_Maybe something even better will come out of your dissatisfaction with `pinia`._

I feel like it already exists - composables. Just put your state to a composable, no troubles of `pinia`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
`authStore.js`:

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { ref } from "vue";

export const useAuthStore = defineStore("authStore", {
  state: () => ({
    email: ref("example@example.com"),
    password: ref("secret"),
  }),
});
```

And then a `Login.vue` component:

```js
<script setup>
import { useAuthStore } from "../stores/authStore.js";
const store = useAuthStore();
</script>

<template>
  <form>
    <input type="email" v-model="store.email" />
    <input type="password" v-model="store.password" />
  </form>
</template>
<style>
input {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 3px;
}
</style>
```

Which seems simpler than the accepted answer.

Comment: Except the v-model doesn't update when the store.email has changed

Comment: @HugoCox except it _does_: https://github.com/nielsbom/vue3-pinia-example/tree/main Have you run the code?